# Communicateur with client-sided serial port through web

Tags: php, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm having an issue with my PHP website (which is using an API, that's why it has to be PHP).

This website is launched on a raspberry pi b+ which is connected to a thermal printer (through serial port), I used a python script to test the printer.

Now my question is: Is it possible to send data through the web to make the raspberry print some data ? So send an instruction like write to the port '/dev/ttyxxx' client sided?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean: "I have a PHP application that needs to access the server's serial port":
It is possible for PHP to access the serial port on the server (in this case, your raspberry pi).  PHP treats it like it is a normal file.

From the [PHP Fopen page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#20935):

```
<?php
// Set timeout to 500 ms
$timeout=microtime(true)+0.5;

// Set device controle options (See man page for stty)
exec("/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyS0 19200 sane raw cs8 hupcl cread clocal -echo -onlcr ");

// Open serial port
$fp=fopen("/dev/ttyS0","c+");
if(!$fp) die("Can't open device");

// Set blocking mode for writing
stream_set_blocking($fp,1);
fwrite($fp,"foo\n");

// Set non blocking mode for reading
stream_set_blocking($fp,0);
do{
  // Try to read one character from the device
  $c=fgetc($fp);

  // Wait for data to arive 
  if($c === false){
      usleep(50000);
      continue;
  }  

  $line.=$c;

}while($c!="\n" && microtime(true)<$timeout); 

echo "Responce: $line";  
?>
```

If you mean: "I have a website that somehow needs to send something to the client's serial port"
Then the only solution is a browser App.

There's the [Chrome Serial API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_serial) which chrome apps can use.
[Video Example](http://renaun.com/blog/2013/05/using-the-chrome-serial-api-with-arduino/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear friend but I think you misunderstood me, or I didn't explain it well. The raspberry isn't the server, but it is the client (kind of like a PoS)! So I need a solution so that the server execudes some magical arcanic code that will allow me to write to the serial port of the client ^^ (or some php code where i can execute my python code). Thank you for helping

Comment: So your raspberry Pi is running a web browser to connect to the PHP website?  Which browser?

Comment: Whatever browser it could need. It runs Linux so i can install Mozilla or Chrome if needed. I just need some solution ^^'

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You're likely limited to the Chrome Serial API (available to Chrome apps and extensions).  http://renaun.com/blog/2013/05/using-the-chrome-serial-api-with-arduino/.

Comment: Hey @Tremmors turned out I'm gonna use my Raspberry Pi as hoster too. So the solution you posted worked good, I just had one problem, the dataflow  is too quick for the thermal printer (like when I write "This is a test!" it shows: "!Z.HZ.HXÉtest!" for some reason). Can you help me out? Thank you already !

Answer (score 0):

I come to think of several solutions; basically you would want your php-page to parse the data and create a **trusted** output that can be printed (i.e. a PDF-file, if your printer supports this).

Your next task is how to have this **trusted** output sent to the printer. Again, several solutions exists.

1. Have your php-script execute a system executable, e.g. `cat output.pdf > /dev/ttyxxx` (it is clear here, that I do not know how to print from unix). Notice that the executable is not dependent on input *at all*, i.e. you want to reduce the risk of injection attacks and the like. This point requires that the output.pdf, that you created, is trustworthy.
2. Have a cron-job look for output files and send them to the printer. Same considerations as above apply. This might be better as it can avoid bottlenecks if multiple php-sessions are trying to print a document.
3. Build a smaller framework around the above that can report back if errors occur etc. But still, basically option 1 + magic.

All in all, split the process into two steps. One that accepts the input, parses and checks for erroneousness/malevolent input, and creates the needed output for the printer. This can be done in a protected environment, which if hacked, does not expose the system (at least not more than the usual php would).
Step 2 then takes care of sending the output to the hardware, either bash-script, executable, or python.

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear friend. Your solution is good, but my problem is that all that has to happens automatically (I press on 1 button on a website = Making the file + execute python code that will print the file)

Is it possible to execute some python script through the web?

Thank you

Comment: Ahh, so the serial port is *not* on the server hosting php, but on the client. php on a server can not execute anything on a client, a priori. It would probably require a browser plugin, where the php script sends an output that the plugin intercepts and can execute on the client, but this is a major security risk!

Comment: Can you @MrGrumble link me some tutorial or some video that showes me how to do that through a plugin? It would be nice.

Thank you for helping.